I am getting an error message when trying to generate a service worker from workbox config file
The error message says
[GenerateSW.ignoreURLParametersMatching.0] GenerateSW.ignoreURLParametersMatching.0 must have required property 'hasIndices'.

And underneath that it says
at validate (directory ...)
at validateGenerateSWOptions (directory ...)
at Object.generateSW (directory ...)
at runBuildCommand (directory ...)
at app (directory ...)

I was following a tutorial and I think I done everything correct up until this point. I tried doing a bit of googling for the error message but nothing seems to come up for it.

I ran into this issue a month back, and the reason was outdated NodeJS while running current workbox.
RegExp indices have been introduced in Node v16.0.0. After upgrading my job was successful again.

This answer could be improved with a more detailed explanation of what you did to perform the upgrade that fixed this error.
